# Modify chunk options via knit_hooks

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to define a custom [chunk hook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-hooks.html) to certain `r-markdown` chunks, which override certain chunk options (`include` and `eval`, basically).

Use case is that I add this chunk option to a chunk, which will hide code and output per default (`include = FALSE`) and evaluates the chunk only if a file exists `eval = <some logic>`. This works if I hardcode it (cf. to chunk `export_disp_mpg_by_hand` but not via a custom chunk option.

But regardless of how I try it, the options are not considered.

### Code

````
---
title: "Chunks Options"
author: "Me"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include = FALSE, message = FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(here)

image_path <- "figs"
if (!dir.exists(here(image_path))) {
  dir.create(here(image_path))
}

knit_hooks$set(export_fig = function(before, options, envir) {
  if (before) {
    fn <- gsub("^export_", "", options$label)
    options$include <- FALSE
    options$eval <- !file.exists(here(image_path, paste0(fn, ".png")))
    ### Does not work either
    ## opts_current$set(include = FALSE, 
    ##                  eval = !file.exists(here(image_path, paste0(fn, ".png"))))
  }
  options
})
```

# Plot

```{r make_plot}
(pl <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) +
   geom_point())
```

```{r export_disp_mpg, export_fig = TRUE}
ggsave(here(image_path, "disp_mpg.png"), pl)
```

```{r export_disp_mpg_by_hand, include = FALSE, eval = !file.exists(here(image_path, "disp_mpg.png"))}
ggsave(here(image_path, "disp_mpg.png"), pl + geom_smooth(method = "lm"))
```
````

### Expected Behaviour

Chunk `export_disp_mpg` should never be shown in the rendered output and the the file it creates should only be created if it is not existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close, I found the solution. In case anybody is interested, I leave the question here with the follwong working answer.

Instead of using `knit_hooks`, one should use `opts_hooks`:

````
```{r setup, include = FALSE}
opts_hooks$set(export_fig = function(options) {
  fn <- gsub("^export_", "", options$label)
  options$include <- FALSE
  options$eval <- !file.exists(here(image_path, paste0(fn, ".png")))
  options
})
```
````